# Pygame Menu Click to Function

Tags: menu, click, pygame

From within a class that is my Main Menu for a pygame game, I am trying to invoke a function. Basically, I have a dictionary in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   functions = {"start": main, "Quit": terminate}
```

My means of having these invoked in my class, upon clicking a menu item is:

```
def runMenu(self):
    mainloop = True
    while mainloop:

        self.__clock.tick(50)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(pygame.mouse.get_pressed())
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mainloop == False
                terminate()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for item in self.items:
                    #print(item.isMouseSelecting(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
                    if item.isMouseSelecting(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        #print(self.__functions)
                        self.__functions[item]() #initialized in the __init__ so that it                                                        holds my dictionary in self.__functions
```

However, I cannot invoke the object reference of each of my functions (main, and terminate). I am not sure of how to get around that. I saw one example where the guy invokes the function by self.__functionsitem.text however that does not work for me as I can't find anything on a .text method and get an attribute error when doing that.

HEre is my error for what I have above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tjleggz/Documents/CS 110/squirrel/squirrel.py", line 501, in <module>
    game.runMenu()
  File "/Users/tjleggz/Documents/CS 110/squirrel/squirrel.py", line 138, in runMenu
    self.__functions[item]() #cant call bc its not same object, just a ref to object or something???@
KeyError: <__main__.MenuItem object at 0x29758c8>
>>>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame Binding Menu items to functions (by clicking)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505226/pygame-binding-menu-items-to-functions-by-clicking)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I correctly understand the question; from the traceback it seems like your `self.items` contains `MenuItem` objects, not strings which are the keys to your dictionary. You can work around this in a couple ways, for example you could give each instance of `MenuItem` a `text` attribute when they are initialized which you could later check with `item.text`.

A better and less redundant way to do this (instead of using a dictionary of functions like you are now) might be to pass an `on_click` function to each `MenuItem` instance you make, and then you just have to write

```
if item.isMouseSelecting(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    item.on_click()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that...This is my first programming class. Could you give me an example? Is on_click a part of pygame or do you mean creating my own?